Link against import lib or dll?
I find I can link against a dll directly using Mingw g++.
g++ -shared -o hello.dll hello.cpp
g++ -o world world.cpp hello.dll

I used to link against the import lib of dll. What are the differences?

The following command
g++ -shared -o hello.dll hello.cpp

does not link against hello.dll but creates a file called hello.dll.
The following command
g++ -o world world.cpp hello.dll

creates world.exe linked against hello.dll.
Though you can specify a .dll file to link directly against it, it's better practice to build the export library along with the .dll file and link against that. Note that the shared export library typically ends with .dll.a in MinGW (not .lib).
To build your shared library I would recommend doing it like this:
g++ -o hellolib.o hello.cpp
g++ -shared -mwindows -o hello.dll hello.o -Wl,--out-implib,libhello.dll.a 

This assumes hello.cpp is the code for you shared library.
This would have to properly export symbols of course using __declspec(dllexport)/__declspec(dllimport).
For a detailed example see:
https://github.com/brechtsanders/ci-test

Yes, this is the normal way I link. I wonder why I could link against the dll directly.

Linking with a DLL directly is also supported in GCC. Since the DLL has information on which symbols it exports the linker the uses that information to link with the DLL.
There's no guarantee other compiler tools also support it, so I would stick with the above method for compatibility.
